# Shouldn't all questions about algorithmic complexity that are not related to programming be migrated to Computer Science or Mathematics?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

While searching for the upper bound of *log(n!)*, I came across the question [Is log(n!) = Θ(n·log(n))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-%CE%98n-logn) on Stack Overflow. This question is neither related to programming nor any "software algorithm" so I don't think it belongs on SO, even though it is well received by the community (has a triple digit score).

I initially thought that Computer Science (CS.SE) would be a better site for the question, but the question is not related to computer science or algorithms at all, but is simply a math question related to complexity theory and the right place for it should be Mathematics (Math.SE), and there are a few similar questions on Mathematics under the [(computational-complexity)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-complexity) tag.

So why has this question, or many others such as the following, not been migrated to Math.SE (or CS.SE)?

- [What is a plain English explanation of “Big O” notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)
- [What is the difference between Θ(n) and O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-%CE%98n-and-on)
- [Is Big O(logn) log base e?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569702/is-big-ologn-log-base-e)
- [Are there any O(1/n) algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905551/are-there-any-o1-n-algorithms)
- Many more can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complexity-theory).

I am aware that the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) mentions that question related to "software algorithms" are on-topic, but none of the questions that I have mentioned are related to "software algorithms", and some are not even related to algorithms; they are purely math related.

**NOTE:**
I agree that about 7 years ago, when CS.SE and Math.SE did not exist, SO might have been the right site to post such questions, but now it makes sense to migrate them to more appropriate sites.

Comment: For migrations the first question to ask is: Are those posts welcomed by the community on the target site. Second criteria: the question doesn't qualify as crap because we don't migrate that either. Third criteria: is it explicitly off-topic on the current site. if not, then migration doesn't make sense.

Comment: **1.** Yes, provided that the OP has done some effort before asking them.
**2.** The question(s) aren't crap. They are quite useful, but not on SO.
**3.** Yes, they certainly are off-topic on SO.

Comment: I have yet to see any of those big-O questions that ARE related to programming where the OP has demonstrated any effort other than copy/paste:(

Comment: As for your explicit examples: those are all questions asked when SO was the only site and back then they weren't off-topic and I'm not convinced they are off-topic now. Although complexity question have a strong theoretical and math foundation, they can also be a practical programming problem faced by programmers. Skimming the recent questions in the tag I don't see a huge problem nor urgency to migrate those. I disagree the questions are off-topic on SO.

Comment: @rene **I didn't say that all the 2500+ questions tagged complexity-theory are off-topic**. The ones that are not at all related to programming and/or algorithms are the ones I am talking about. There are a few of them (probably around 100) but those are definitely off-topic.

Comment: [help/on-topic] lists "software algorithm" as on-topic

Comment: @gnat Yes I am aware of that, and none of the questions I mentioned are any way related to "software algorithm". They are purely math related.

Comment: consider [edit]ing your post to help readers see that you are aware of that and that you are taking this into account. That said I find it rather difficult to explain that example questions you listed aren't related to software (to me it also feels they aren't but I just can't put my finger on something there and say "see, that's why they aren't")

Comment: we welcome better coordination/ collaboration between the sites and [cs.se] esp mods/ high rep users, feel free to drop by our chat at [cs.se] for further discussion. maybe the sites might find some benefit to migrating old questions to better fit, or maybe not. at least figuring out boundaries more & communicating them seems useful/ helpful/ beneficial to everyone...

Answer (score 2):

It's often very hard to draw a sharp line between topic and off-topic.

One could, as you do, reasonably argue that it's not about programming or algorithms, but a pure math question. While what you are saying is technically true, complexity analysis is hardly ever relevant in any other field than computer science. Or at least computer science is by far the biggest user of complexity analysis.

So yes, questions about complexity analysis that are not related to programming should be considered off-topic, but in practice, almost all of them are.

Comment: I get your point but if you consider these answer on topic then almost half of the question on CS.SE are on topic on SO. And probably the other half could be split between the other branches of SE. What I'm trying to say is that even if it could be seen, in practice, as on topic on SO it surely is on topic in other SE sites and it should be migrated to the site which it belongs most.